How to install pyqt6-webengine on msys2
I can install pyqt6 by pacman in msys2 use the command:
pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-python-pyqt6.

But it does not have the WebEngine as I try to import it:
from PyQt6 import QtWebEngineWidgets

ImportError: cannot import name 'QtWebEngineWidgets' from 'PyQt6' (unknown location)

And I cannot find PyQt6-WebEngine package in msys2 pacman.
When I try to install the PyQt6-WebEngine package by pip, it always get this error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "D:/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "D:/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "D:/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 152, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
          whl_basename = backend.build_wheel(metadata_directory, config_settings)
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "D:/msys64/tmp/pip-build-env-tjhf207u/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sipbuild/api.py", line 46, in build_wheel
          project = AbstractProject.bootstrap('wheel',
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "D:/msys64/tmp/pip-build-env-tjhf207u/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sipbuild/abstract_project.py", line 92, in bootstrap
          project.setup(pyproject, tool, tool_description)
        File "D:/msys64/tmp/pip-build-env-tjhf207u/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sipbuild/project.py", line 587, in setup
          self.apply_user_defaults(tool)
        File "D:/msys64/tmp/pip-build-env-tjhf207u/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyqtbuild/project.py", line 51, in apply_user_defaults
          super().apply_user_defaults(tool)
        File "D:/msys64/tmp/pip-build-env-tjhf207u/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sipbuild/project.py", line 237, in apply_user_defaults
          self.builder.apply_user_defaults(tool)
        File "D:/msys64/tmp/pip-build-env-tjhf207u/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyqtbuild/builder.py", line 50, in apply_user_defaults
          raise PyProjectOptionException('qmake',
      sipbuild.pyproject.PyProjectOptionException

So what should I do to install PyQt6 WebEngine?

as I know QtWebEngineWidgets is not part of PyQt (at least for PyQt5) and it need to install it separately using pip. Check python modules on pypi.org - Search results for PyQtWebEngine - and it may need pip install PyQt6-WebEngine
